# Error in "apply(grps, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))) : dim(X) must have a positive length" at running dht2 function in R

Tags: r

I am running the script from de Distance examples (http://examples.distancesampling.org/Distance-cues/cuecounts-distill.html) to estimate density using function dht2 of Distance library but I have an error.

The script is:

```
library (Distance)
data(wren_cuecount)
conversion.factor <- convert_units("meter", NULL, "hectare")
wren_cuecount$Effort <- wren_cuecount$Search.time
wrensong.hr <- ds(wren_cuecount, transect="point", key="hr", adjustment=NULL, 
                  truncation=100)
cuerate <- unique(wren_cuecount[ , c("Cue.rate","Cue.rate.SE")])
names(cuerate) <- c("rate", "SE")
(mult <- list(creation=cuerate))
wren.estimate <- dht2(wrensong.hr, flatfile=wren_cuecount, strat_formula=~1,
                      multipliers=mult, convert_units=conversion.factor)
print(wren.estimate, report="density")""
```

When I run the dht2 function I get:

> Error in apply(grps, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))) :    dim(X) must
> have a positive length

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so that it can be understood.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would suggest inspecting some of the intermediate objects such as `wrengsong.hr`, `wren_cuecount`, `mult`, etc. to ensure that they match the expected inputs of those functions.